# distinct drops columns after group_by

Tags: r, dplyr

After doing a group_by I can't get distinct values unless I change the object back to a data frame.

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), B = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), C = c(6,6,6,5,5,5))
y <- x %>% group_by(A) %>% transmute(B = mean(B), C = mean(C))
y
distinct(y)
distinct(as.data.frame(y))
```

This behaviour seems to have changed after a recent dplyr release (I have dplyr_0.5.0) as I'm sure my code used to work. The question is, is this a bug or by design? If by design, I need to change a bunch of code. Thanks!

Comment: Can you also display your desired output?

Comment: Hi @Megatron my desired output is `distinct(as.data.frame(y))` but the code I have is `distinct(y)`. I'm not after a coding solution - I have that. What I want to know is should I go and change all my code or is this a bug that will be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
library(dplyr)
x <- data.frame(A = c(1,1,2,2,3,3), B = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), C = c(6,6,6,5,5,5))
y <- x %>% group_by(A) %>% transmute(B = mean(B), C = mean(C)) %>% ungroup()
y
distinct(y)
distinct(as.data.frame(y))
```

note the `ungroup()`